# How do 'for' loops in lists work in Python?

Tags: python

How does the *for* loop work in lists? Where can I find the documentation for this?

Sometimes when I look at other posts on Stack Overflow I see this:

```
my_list = [x.split(",") for x in my_list]
```

(I tried looking it up on the documentation, but I couldn’t find it.)

Comment: Its called a list comprehension: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called List Comprehensions and it is basically a quick way to build a sequence. The code you demonstrate basically means,

> for each `x` in `my_list`, perform `x.split(",")`, and then put all the result in a new list, which is then passed to `my_list`.

It is equivalent to:

```
new_list = []

for x in my_list:
    y = x.split(",")
    new_list.append(y)

my_list = new_list
```

So you can see with list comprehensions it is a lot simpler.